# main loop function doesn't run nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

I'm new in the JavaScript and programming world and I'm struggling with a basic JavaScript exercise, I should create with just basic functions a times table based on a user prompt value, it should a loop that interrupts just when the user insert the value -1. 
Although, the loop doesn't print the times table until I interrupt the loop with the -1, it seems like it's looping too fast.

Here he's my code:

```js
var userInput;

function checkValidity(question) {

  if(isNaN(question) || (question === "" )) {
    console.log('Inserire un numero valido');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('defined');
    return true;
  }
}

function timeTable(valueUser) {
  document.write("Times Table for number: " + valueUser + "<br />");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {     
    document.write(valueUser + " * " + i + " = " + valueUser * i + "<br />");
  }

}

function showQuestion() {
  userInput = parseInt(prompt("Enter your Times Table value:"));
  
  var answerValidate = checkValidity(userInput);

  if(answerValidate) {
    if(userInput !== -1) {
      timeTable(userInput);
      showQuestion();
    } else {
      console.log("Grazie per aver partecipato!");
    }
  } else {
    showQuestion();
  }

  
}

showQuestion();
```

Anyone that can suggest me in what I'm wrong?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Please format your code properly, especially: Remove the massive intendation

Comment: As of now, the loop merely prints the value passed to timeTable ten times and then returns to the caller. The loop should rather be set up in the calling function (I'd recommend a `while` loop here, and you would also want to avoid the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` doesn't do its job right away, it just puts the job on the queue and the "browser" will do that job when it has nothing else to do. By calling `showQuestion` directly after those `document.write` calls, you keep the "browser" occupied. So it will do those accumulated jobs once the recursion has stopped (when the user enter `-1`).

To fix this, just put the next call to `showQuestion` on queue as well using `setTimeout` without a delay (or a 0 delay):

```
setTimeout(showQuestion);
```

**Example:**

```js
var userInput;

function checkValidity(question) {

  if(isNaN(question) || (question === "" )) {
    console.log('Inserire un numero valido');
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log('defined');
    return true;
  }
}

function timeTable(valueUser) {
  document.write("Times Table for number: " + valueUser + "<br />");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {     
    document.write(valueUser + " * " + i + " = " + valueUser * i + "<br />");
  }

}

function showQuestion() {
  userInput = parseInt(prompt("Enter your Times Table value:"));
  
  var answerValidate = checkValidity(userInput);

  if(answerValidate) {
    if(userInput !== -1) {
      timeTable(userInput);
      setTimeout(showQuestion);
    } else {
      console.log("Grazie per aver partecipato!");
    }
  } else {
    showQuestion();
  }
}

showQuestion();
```

With that being said, I advice you not to use `document.write` at all, use an alternative like `console.log` or change the `textContent` of a particular element. Also, use an `<input>` element instead of the intrusive `prompt` calls. No looping is needed here, the user can enter as many values as he likes whenever he likes.

**Example:**

```js
function timesTable(valueUser) {
  var result = "Times Table for number: " + valueUser + "\n";          // accumulate the result in a string (use "\n" instead of "<br>")
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {     
    result += valueUser + " * " + i + " = " + valueUser * i + "\n";
  }
   
  return result;                                                       // and return it
}

function showQuestion() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("my-input").value);     // get the value from the input
  
  if(isNaN(value)) {                                                   // if it is not valid
    alert("Invalid input! Try again!");                                // alert the user and urge him to start over
  } else {                                                             // otherwise
    document.getElementById("my-result").textContent = timesTable(value); // create the times table of this number and show them in the my-result element 
  }
}

document.getElementById("my-button").onclick = function() {            // when the button is clicked
    showQuestion();                                                    // call showQuestion
};
```

```html
<input id="my-input"><button id="my-button">Show times table</button>
<pre id="my-result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works perfectly fine. What you're missing is that `prompt()` is blocking and no javascript can run until this function returns.

To avoid this, don't use `prompt()` but a simple `<input type="text" />`. That will, obviously, kick you out of the synchronized paradigm you are using and require to restructure your code in an asynchronous way. That's very easy to do, really. This should get you going:

```
<input id="campo_di_testo" type="text" /><input id="bottone_invia" type="button" value="invia" />

<script>

  document.getElementById("bottone_invia").onclick = () => {
    var textNode;

    textNode = document.getElementById("campo_di_testo");
    console.log("hai premuto invia e il testo immesso è: " + textNode.value);
  };

</script>
```

In addition avoid using `document.write()` as Ibrahim points out. It will overwrite the DOM tree and remove the `<input>` elements.

You can use a `<textarea>` like this:

```
<textarea id="area"></textarea>

// in JS:
var area = document.getElementById("area");
area.value += "nuova riga da appendere" + "\n";
                                          ^^^^ don't forget to append the newline
```

or, similarly, any `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="output"></div>

// in JS:
var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerText += "nuova riga da appendere" + "<br />";
```